# One Adwords API Developer Token for multiple accounts?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have to download report from multiple Adwords accounts, they are not linked under the same MCC hierarchy. I have registered with one of them and have a developer token for that account. Now I want to use this developer token with all other accounts if it is possible to download report.
Can I use one developer token for multiple Adwords account? These accounts are independent and they are not linked under the same MCC hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one Developer Token to access multiple accounts. A Developer Token identifies you as an AdWords API developer, and isn't tied to a single MCC. You will need to obtain separate OAuth tokens to access each account.